# Unable to left align title and author name using titling package in an existing template

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titling

I am using an existing template that uses "titling". By default, the title is center aligned. I wanted to left align the title so that I may write my name in the same line. I know that there are so many questions on aligning (I am extremely new to latex), but the problem is trying them gives me one error or the other.

I just want to get it working using the existing template I have.

This is what I want to make it work on -

```tex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
% \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}
\setlength{\droptitle}{-0.75in}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\title{Letter of Motivation \vspace{-0.6in}}
\author{Your Name}%\vspace{-0.25in}
\date{\vspace{-0.7in}} %0.5 was default

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\noindent
Lorem Ipsum hello world blah blah...
```

Now the author name and title overlap.

What I want is that the title is left aligned and after some space the author name appears (writing author name as part of title is fine too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `titling` package offers `\pretitle`, `\posttitle`, `\preauthor`, `\postauthor`, `\predate`, and `\postdate` with the help of which you can configure the output of the `\maketitle` command.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titling}

\setlength{\droptitle}{-0.75in}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Letter of Motivation}
\author{Your Name}
\date{}

\pretitle{\noindent\LARGE}
\posttitle{}
\preauthor{\hspace{3cm}\large} % adjust distance between title and author to your needs (currently 3cm)
%\preauthor{\hfill\large} % uncomment for left aligned title and right aligned author
\postauthor{\par \vskip 0.2em}
\predate{}
\postdate{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\noindent
Lorem Ipsum hello world blah blah...


\end{document}
```